# Payments Not Enabled on Mobile,Why?

Tags: facebook, mobile, payment

My app can not do Canvas payment on brower of mobile phone,it get error tips below:
**

```
error occurred. Please try later
API Error Code: 1178
API Error Description: This app doesn't let you make purchases from your mobile phone.
Error Message: App not enabled on mobile.
```

**

how can I do to enable payment on mobile phone?